# Why did Captain Archer compete at boxing?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

I understand that Captain Archer's hand skills saved his life and the lives of others more than once. I also understand that Captain Archer had to frequently time travel, due to the temporal cold war (which wasn't really all that cold).

However, I am confused as to why Captain Archer competed in boxing while traveling back to 20th century Earth?

[image: Captain Archer boxing in the past]

Comment: This is the best question I've ever seen on here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### He didn't

That image isn't from *Star Trek Enterprise*; it's from [*Quantum Leap*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096684/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), an unrelated sci-fi series also starring Scott Bakula (who played Archer on *Enterprise*).

Specifically, the image is from ["The Right Hand of God"](http://quantumleap.wikia.com/wiki/The_Right_Hand_of_God_(episode)), the third episode of season 1; [this fansite has collected more images from the episode](http://quantum-stills.blogspot.ca/2011/01/right-hand-of-god-part-i.html), including a few very similar to the one in the question.

[image]

[image]

The premise of Quantum Leap is that Bakula's character has his consciousness sent through time, where it inhabits various historical personages. In "The Right Hand of God", he inhabits the body of a Sacramento boxer in 1974, where he has to win at boxing match to help some nuns build a new chapel.

Comment: Got it. Quantum Leap isn't an episode, it's a different series.

Comment: @y0gapants Got it in one. *Quantum Leap* is the other reason anyone interested in science fiction cares about Scott Bakula

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=As2Vd_mYnAk

Comment: I was getting ready to make a joke about Ziggy telling him to, but then I scrolled down and saw it really was from Quantum Leap.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why Captain Picard needs a wheelchair, or how Captain Janeway ended up married to Columbo.